# CognitiveのCustom Speechについて

Tags: azure

Custom Speechを使って、日本語の文字起こしについての問題です。
例えば、「朝夕」は二つの読み方があります。「あさゆう」と「ちょうせき」
「ちょうせき」＞朝夕　に文字起こしする精度が悪い時、「ちょうせき」＞朝夕　を学習させたい場合、
どうすればよろしいでしょうか。